# Limited size hash map

Tags: java

I'd like to make an hash map to use like a cache.
Cache has an initial size, if you try inserting an item when cache is full last recently used item should be replaced...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html. I quite sure that you can take that implementation from the AOSP and use it under the Apache License.

Comment: Thanks I'm developing for android so it's just what I needed^^

Answer (score 19):

You can use a LinkedHashMap by implementing [removeEldest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry%28java.util.Map.Entry%29)

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> lruCache(final int maxSize) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxSize*4/3, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxSize;
        }
    };
}
```

For more details

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/java-secret-lru-cache-in-java.html

http://blog.meschberger.ch/2008/10/linkedhashmaps-hidden-features.html

Comment: maxSize*4/3 or did u mean * 3/4?

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) ? It has factory-based methods for creating collections with [caches](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) etc.

e.g. (from the linked article)

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Comment: Guava is a cool library but LinkedHashMap happens to do exactly what was asked for.

Comment: True but then again if he's going down the path of using it as a Cache the Guava library has a lot of other useful things like the expireAfterWrite displayed here.

Comment: Yes. The Guava solutions offer a lot, not just for this scenario but for many others.

Comment: You also need to consider that adding Guava to an Android project/module adds about 12k methods and fields and dex has a limit of 65k.

Answer (score 1):

The most trivial approach would be to extend `LinkedHashMap`, override the `removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest)` method and decide in its implementation if your cache is "full" or not.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LRUMap.html) from Apache Commons.

> A Map implementation with a fixed maximum size which removes the least recently used entry if an entry is added when full.
>
> The least recently used algorithm works on the get and put operations only. Iteration of any kind, including setting the value by iteration, does not change the order. Queries such as containsKey and containsValue or access via views also do not change the order.
>
> The map implements OrderedMap and entries may be queried using the bidirectional OrderedMapIterator. The order returned is least recently used to most recently used. Iterators from map views can also be cast to OrderedIterator if required.
>
> All the available iterators can be reset back to the start by casting to ResettableIterator and calling reset().
>
> Note that LRUMap is not synchronized and is not thread-safe. If you wish to use this map from multiple threads concurrently, you must use appropriate synchronization. The simplest approach is to wrap this map using Collections.synchronizedMap(Map). This class may throw NullPointerException's when accessed by concurrent threads.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a bound queue together with your hash map. In that way you would easily know which item is the oldest.